# How to flatten an object array to JSON dynamically (creating new property for each) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, data-conversion, converters

My API is receiving JSON from an internal endpoint that returns a "Document" object. In this "Document" object there is an array of 'Descriptor' objects. The descriptor objects are in the following format in JSON and as a Model respectively.

```
   "Descriptors":[ 
       {
    "name": "Color",
    "value": "Red",
    "searchable_value": "Red"
       },
       {
    "name": "Shape",
    "value": "Sphere",
    "searchable_value": "Round"
       }
    ]

public class Descriptor
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name;

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value;

    [JsonProperty("SearchableValue")]
    public string SearchableValue;
}

public class Document
{
// other properties

        [JsonProperty("Descriptors")]
        public List<Descriptor> Descriptors;

}
```

The conversion is done via

```
var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream));
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Document>(jsonReader);
```

I need to take this Document object and convert it to JSON again to send away, but in this new JSON I need the descriptors to be flattened dynamically to the top level of the Document and have one entry for each descriptor.

Using the example above, the descriptor array would be flattened in JSON to

```
// the rest of the Document JSON properties
{
"descriptor_colour": "Red",
"descriptor_colour_searchable_value": "Red"
},
{
"descriptor_shape": "Sphere",
"descriptor_shape_searchable_value": "Round"
}
```

This will need to be done for each descriptor in the array and there are a variable number of descriptors for each Document i.e. If in one document there are 5 descriptors we would need 5 blocks of JSON at the top level along with everything else the Document contains, If in another there are 27 descriptors I need 27 blocks etc.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this using JSON converters and am stuck, Any ideas?

Comment: I don't like where this is going.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON. however, as a fragment of JSON it can be the contents of an array. The easiest way to solve this is to create a C# model that serializes to the desired output and convert the input model to the output model before serializing it.